# Is there a way you could set the height of a CupertinoNavigationBar like you can with AppBar

Tags: flutter

I have problem setting the size of my `CupertinoNavigationBar` manually, and I know you would be able to do it for the `appBar` using the `PreferredSize` Widget by doing the following:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
  child: AppBar(
    flexibleSpace: Widget(),
  )
),
```

However if you try this for the `CupertinoNavigationBar` you get an error that states:

> 'AppBar' is not a subtype of type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'

Is there any known way that you could set the height of the `CupertinoNavigationBar` manually?

Answer (score 0):

From digging around a little in the CupertinoNavigationBar it appears the size is predetermined but is also based off of the MediaQuery padding. Now, this is very much a "hack" but it does appear to give you **kind of** the behavior you're after. The main issue with this is that this solution uses the Cupertino*Sliver*NavigationBar instead of the base one. Which means that as you scroll up the transform target gets placed above the "middle" section in a rather ugly fashion. You could probably figure some way around that. I tried the solution without it being a Sliver and it didn't work properly. I personally think that building your own version of the CupertinoNavigationBar is the simplest way to overcome the static heights the Flutter team implemented. What I've done is used the CompositedTransformFollower/Target widgets and forced the appbar height with the MediaQuery widget. Here's the code:

```
//outside of build method 
final LinkLayer link = LinkLayer();

//within build method
MediaQuery (
  data: MediaQuery.of (context).copyWith (
      padding: MediaQuery.of (context).padding.copyWith (
          top: MediaQuery.of (context).padding.top + 90
      )
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[

      CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar (
            largeTitle: CompositedTransformTarget(
              link: link,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 130,
                height: 110,
              ),
            ),
            middle: Text('middle'),
          )
        ],
      ),

      CompositedTransformFollower(
        link: link,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              height: 110,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

If you choose to copy the CupertinoNavigationBar then the const you'll want to work around is: _kNavBarPersistentHeight.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your child of CupertinoPageScaffold by SafeArea